# Recursive function in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, react-redux, reactstrap

I am making dynamic menus using a recursive function and I have already made the menus and it display in the right order without any issues.

And I receive the data for menu from **service.js** file and you can see the entire working application in the below code sandbox example,

> [**https://codesandbox.io/s/reactstrap-accordion-3uoz9**](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactstrap-accordion-3uoz9)

**Requirement:**

Here I am in the need to find out the **last level of menus** and need to assign checkbox with value as their respective id `{item.id}`.

**Eg:**

For First menu **one**,

```
 -> [Checkbox with value as 1.1.1] One-One-One
 -> [Checkbox with value as 1.1.2] One - one - two
 -> [Checkbox with value as 1.1.3] One - one - three
```

For Second menu **two**,

```
 -> [Checkbox with value as 2.1] Two - one
```

.

.

.

For sixth menu **six**,

```
 -> [Checkbox with value as 6] Six
```

I hope the point is clear that I need to find out the last level in recursion and should assign a checkbox to it with the value of their id.

Please fork the code sandbox provided and help me to achieve the result of making the checkbox at the last level.

**Optional requirement:**
The collapse is working for whole menus at once if possible please make it collapse at each individual level in unique.

But the main important requirement is to make a checkbox at the last level of menus. 
A big thanks in advance...

**Edit:**

As commented by Crowder, I have created the snippet removing reactstrap code and it is okay now because I am in the need of displaying checkbox inline to laste level of submenus (last children elements).

```js
const menuData = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "One",
    children: [
      {
        id: "1.1",
        name: "One - one",
        children: [
          { id: "1.1.1", name: "One - one - one" },
          { id: "1.1.2", name: "One - one - two" },
          { id: "1.1.3", name: "One - one - three" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Two",
    children: [{ id: "2.1", name: "Two - one" }]
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Three",
    children: [
      {
        id: "3.1",
        name: "Three - one",
        children: [
          {
            id: "3.1.1",
            name: "Three - one - one",
            children: [
              {
                id: "3.1.1.1",
                name: "Three - one - one - one",
                children: [
                  { id: "3.1.1.1.1", name: "Three - one - one - one - one" }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { id: "4", name: "Four" },
  {
    id: "5",
    name: "Five",
    children: [
      { id: "5.1", name: "Five - one" },
      { id: "5.2", name: "Five - two" },
      { id: "5.3", name: "Five - three" },
      { id: "5.4", name: "Five - four" }
    ]
  },
  { id: "6", name: "Six" }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      currentSelection: "",
      menuItems: [],
      isToggleOpen: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ menuItems: menuData });
  }

  handleClick(id, evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log("click handler called with", id);
    this.setState({ currentSelection: id });
  }

  toggle() {
    console.log(this.state);
    this.setState({
      isToggleOpen: !this.state.isToggleOpen
    });
  }

  buildMenu(items) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {items &&
          items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <div>
                {item.name}
                {item.children && item.children.length > 0
                  ? this.buildMenu(item.children)
                  : null}
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Click any of the below option</h2>
        {this.state.menuItems &&
          this.state.menuItems.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                {item.name}
                {this.buildMenu(item.children)}
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reactstrap/4.8.0/reactstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reactstrap/4.8.0/reactstrap.min.css" />
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, If I am not wrong this is how react OP's will post the question and provide a link to code sandbox that is what I see maximum in Stack Overflow.. Even for angular also they provide Stackblitz link.. Even people ask for minum reproducible link in such link only. mainly in react.

Comment: I am not sure who has downvoted eventhough my question is very clear and I have tried maximum attempts..

Comment: **Where** do you need to get that `id`? I can't tell looking at the question where you're planning to use it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Say I am using reactstrap (a react bootstrap) library for collapsible menu will that still work in snippet here?? I have tried but it doesn't.. Anyhow I will post the snippet as like you said.. For ```id``` it is available in ```service.js``` file in the example link provided .. Unless you click on that link you won't get idea but as you said I will try to reproduce the snippet here but I am not sure of calling ```service.js``` file inside ```index.js``` file here.. But let me try..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I am unable to find the way to create two different files such ```index.js``` and ```service.js``` in the code snippet as it allows only one file at a time.. May I get your help from you to do it..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I have created the things in a single file but I am getting an error as ```"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: render is not defined",``` .. Please help me to achieve the result Crowder.. I have provided the array in which I am trying to do the recursion..

Comment: I've fixed a couple of basic errors (it's `ReactDOM.render`, not just `render`, as you could see from the examples I linked to twice above; and you put `menuData` in your constructor, but then referred to it elsewhere), but the snippet still has irrelevancies in it that prevent it running (such as `Button`). I'm afraid i'm out for the afternoon so won't be able to help. FWIW, though, here's a sketch of how `buildMenu` could return the bottom-level `id`: https://pastebin.com/YkQHrZY9

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I have made a simple snippet of actually of what I am in the need.. So can you help me now.. Before the last level I am in the need to assign checkbox with respective id as value..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Could you please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616336/open-the-collapsible-menu-by-default-based-on-the-id where I have used only snippet of SO..

Answer (score 0):

```
buildMenu(items) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {items &&
          items.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <div>
                {this.state.isToggleOpen}
                {(item.children) ?  'Not Last': 'Here you can apply your check box'} //this check if item have children 
                <Button onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}> {item.name} {index} </Button>

                <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isToggleOpen}>
                  {item.children && item.children.length > 0
                    ? this.buildMenu(item.children, index)
                    : null}
                </Collapse>
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
```

Now second case on render

```
<Button onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}> {item.name}</Button>
```

Check if item have children

```
{(item.children) ? this.buildMenu(item.children) : 'Apply your checkbox here'}
```

Full Code

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { loadMenu } from "./service";
import { Button, Collapse } from "reactstrap";

// const buildMenu = function buildMenu(items)

// const Menu = ({ items }) => buildMenu(items);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentSelection: "",
      menuItems: [],
      isToggleOpen: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    loadMenu().then(items => this.setState({ menuItems: items }));
  }

  handleClick(id, evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log("click handler called with", id);
    this.setState({ currentSelection: id });
  }

  toggle() {
    console.log(this.state);
    this.setState({
      isToggleOpen: !this.state.isToggleOpen
    });
  }

  buildMenu(items) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {items &&
          items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <div>
                {this.state.isToggleOpen}
                {(item.children) ?  'Not Last': 'Here you can apply your check box'}
                <Button onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}> {item.name} </Button>
                <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isToggleOpen}>
                  {item.children && item.children.length > 0
                    ? this.buildMenu(item.children)
                    : null}
                </Collapse>
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.menuItems);
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Click any of the below option</h2>
        {this.state.menuItems &&
          this.state.menuItems.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <Button onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}> {item.name} </Button>
                {(item.children) ?  'Not Last': 'Here you can apply your check box'}
                <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isToggleOpen}>
                  {this.buildMenu(item.children)}
                </Collapse>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Let me know the reason for down voting my answer  as {(item.children) ?  'Not Last': 'Here you can apply your check box'}  will check if item have any further children and 
if there isn't then user can apply checkbox. Just downvoting without reason isn't a way. If there is anything wrong I will appreciate the downvote. Whosoever downvoted.

Comment: @TestUser I haven't added the checkbox but you can get the last element using the code. Just replace your buildMenu method with the upper one. and add {(item.children) ? this.buildMenu(item.children) : 'Apply your checkbox here'} in the <Button> used in render.

Comment: It doesn't work for first level only for eg.., ```four``` and ```six```..

Comment: I am in the need to assign check box with respective to the last item as like I have given in question ```[Checkbox with value as 1.1.1] One-One-One```  checkbox at left and the respective text at right with checkbox value as ```id``` but unfortunately your solution doesn't meet my need.. Anyhow your help and time is much appreciated..