# Toggle only the menu clicked in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion, reactstrap

I am making a menu and submenus using `recursion function` and I am in the need of help to open only the respective menu and sub menu's..

For button and collapse [Reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) has been used..

**Recursive function that did menu population**:

```
{this.state.menuItems &&
          this.state.menuItems.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={item.id}>
                <Button onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}> {item.name} </Button>
                <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isToggleOpen}>
                  {this.buildMenu(item.children)}
                </Collapse>
              </div>
            );
          })}
```

And the `buildMenu` function as follows,

```
  buildMenu(items) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {items &&
          items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <div>
                {this.state.isToggleOpen}
                <Button onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}> {item.name} </Button>
                <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isToggleOpen}>
                  {item.children && item.children.length > 0
                    ? this.buildMenu(item.children)
                    : null}
                </Collapse>
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
```

There is no problem with the code as of now but I am in the need of help to make `menu -> submenu -> submenu` step by step open and closing respective levels.

Working example: [**https://codesandbox.io/s/reactstrap-accordion-9epsp**](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactstrap-accordion-9epsp)

You can take a look at this example that when you click on any menu the whole level of menus gets opened instead of clicked one..

**Requirement**

If user clicked on menu `One`, then the submenu (children)

```
-> One-One
```

needs to get opened.

And then if user clicked on `One-One`,

```
 ->   One-One-One
 ->   One - one - two
 ->   One - one - three
```

needs to get opened.

Likewise it is nested so after click on any menu/ children their respective next level needs to get opened.

I am new in react and reactstrap way of design , So any help from expertise would be useful for me to proceed and learn how actually it needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using one large component, consider splitting up your component into smaller once. This way you can add state to each menu item to toggle the underlying menu items.

If you want to reset al underlying menu items to their default closed position you should create a new component instance each time you open up a the underlying buttons. By having `<MenuItemContainer key={timesOpened}` the `MenuItemContainer` will be assigned a new key when you "open" the `MenuItem`. Assigning a new key will create a new component instance rather than updating the existing one.

For a detailed explanation I suggest reading [You Probably Don't Need Derived State - Recommendation: Fully uncontrolled component with a `key`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key).

```js
const loadMenu = () => Promise.resolve([{id:"1",name:"One",children:[{id:"1.1",name:"One - one",children:[{id:"1.1.1",name:"One - one - one"},{id:"1.1.2",name:"One - one - two"},{id:"1.1.3",name:"One - one - three"}]}]},{id:"2",name:"Two",children:[{id:"2.1",name:"Two - one"}]},{id:"3",name:"Three",children:[{id:"3.1",name:"Three - one",children:[{id:"3.1.1",name:"Three - one - one",children:[{id:"3.1.1.1",name:"Three - one - one - one",children:[{id:"3.1.1.1.1",name:"Three - one - one - one - one"}]}]}]}]},{id:"4",name:"Four"},{id:"5",name:"Five",children:[{id:"5.1",name:"Five - one"},{id:"5.2",name:"Five - two"},{id:"5.3",name:"Five - three"},{id:"5.4",name:"Five - four"}]},{id:"6",name:"Six"}]);

const {Component, Fragment} = React;
const {Button, Collapse} = Reactstrap;

class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {menuItems: []};
  }

  render() {
    const {menuItems} = this.state;
    return <MenuItemContainer menuItems={menuItems} />;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    loadMenu().then(menuItems => this.setState({menuItems}));
  }
}

class MenuItemContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    const {menuItems} = this.props;
    if (!menuItems.length) return null;
    return <ul>{menuItems.map(this.renderMenuItem)}</ul>;
  }
  
  renderMenuItem(menuItem) {
    const {id} = menuItem;
    return <li key={id}><MenuItem {...menuItem} /></li>;
  }
}
MenuItemContainer.defaultProps = {menuItems: []};

class MenuItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isOpen: false, timesOpened: 0};
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    const {name, children} = this.props;
    const {isOpen, timesOpened} = this.state;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Button onClick={isOpen ? this.close : this.open}>{name}</Button>
        <Collapse isOpen={isOpen}>
          <MenuItemContainer key={timesOpened} menuItems={children} />
        </Collapse>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }

  open() {
    this.setState(({timesOpened}) => ({
      isOpen: true,
      timesOpened: timesOpened + 1,
    }));
  }
  
  close() {
    this.setState({isOpen: false});
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Menu />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reactstrap/8.4.1/reactstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I am making it as accepted but I am also having an issue here as like I am mentioned in the other solution.. If I open upto last level menu opening wise it is working fine first time.. Then if I close it at say (second level), and again if I click on the seond level, the next level only should open but it opens until the last level.. So closing the menus in one level and again opening showing all the levels instead of next level.. Please look into it and update your answer

Comment: @TestUser I've updated the answer based upon the requirements. I do feel like the ref solution is not the best way to go, but it's late and this was the easy way to go. I'll rewatch the problem tomorrow to see if I can find something better.

Comment: Yes please update the solution if possible with the best method.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you help me in this question please?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616336/open-the-collapsible-menu-by-default-based-on-the-id

Comment: @TestUser I've refactored the solution to use a "Fully uncontrolled component with a key" solution. Check out the link provided in the answer. I'll have a look at the new question later today.

Comment: Okay I will look into this, kindly look into the new question once you are free to do..

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create an inner component to manage the state at each level.

For example, consider the following functional component (I'll leave it to you to convert to class component):

```js
const MenuButton = ({ name, children }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = useCallback(() => setOpen(o => !o), [setOpen]);
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={toggle}>{name}</Button>
      <Collapse open={open}>{children}</Collapse>
    </>
  );
};
```

This component will manage whether to display its children or not. Use it in place of all of your `<div><Button/><Collapse/></div>` sections, and it will manage the open state for each level.

Keep shared state up at the top, but if you don't need to know whether something is expanded for other logic, keep it localized.

Also, if you do need that info in your parent component, use the predefined object you already have and add an 'open' field to it which defaults to false. Upon clicking, setState on that object to correctly mark the appropriate object to have the parameter of true on open.

Localized state is much cleaner though.

**Expanded Example**

```js
import React, { Component, useState, useCallback, Fragment } from "react";
import { Collapse, Button } from "reactstrap";
import { loadMenu } from "./service";


const MenuButton = ({ name, children }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const toggle = useCallback(() => setOpen(o => !o), [setOpen]);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Button onClick={toggle}>{name}</Button>
      <Collapse open={open}>{children}</Collapse>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

class Hello extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentSelection: "",
      menuItems: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    loadMenu().then(items => this.setState({ menuItems: items }));
  }

  buildMenu(items) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {items &&
          items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <MenuButton name={item.name}>
              {item.children && item.children.length > 0
                    ? this.buildMenu(item.children)
                    : null}
              </MenuButton>
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Click any of the below option</h2>
        {this.state.menuItems &&
          this.state.menuItems.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <MenuButton name={item.name}>
                {this.buildMenu(item.children)}
              </MenuButton>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Hello;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. Could you please fork my code sandbox and give me right solution which would be really help me to understand better..

Comment: I added an expanded example in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help will implement this in my real application.. But for what I have shown here in codesandbox you have made it working so your work is much appreciated and I am going to upvote and accept it.. As you have helpmed me here I think you might also be able solve my another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60600098/recursive-function-in-reactjs  .. At the last level of menus I am in the need of checkbox inline with the last level menu items..

Comment: Also I have found a flaw here in your solution, if I open upto last level menu opening wise it is working fine first time.. Then if I close it at say (second level), and again if I click on the seond level, the next level only should open but it opens until the last level.. So closing the menus in one level and again opening showing all the levels instead of next level.. Please look into it and update your answer..